# Windows CLI, redirect command output into variable error "The system cannot find the file ffprobe."

Tags: windows, shell

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %g IN (ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_entries stream=width -of csv=p=0:s=x 1.mp4) do SET width=%g
```

When executing this command, I receive the error

> The system cannot find the file ffprobe.

However, when I run the command `ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_entries stream=width -of csv=p=0:s=x 1.mp4`, ffprobe runs just fine and outputs the width of 1.mp4

Answer (score 0):

You are asking `for` to read files, not execute a command. Depending on the quote character, `for` can parse a string or run a command. Run `for /?` for the details.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %g in ('ping localhost^|find "Reply"') do @echo.%g
```